# Crystal Reports -- How to show after decimal value differentnly in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show after decimal 2 value in report but there a condition if value meet that condition then need to show full value. formula is given below but it is giving error

```
if trim({As400InTemp.PARTYCODE})='006883'  then
      {As400InTemp.SPPRIC}
else
      round({As400InTemp.SPPRIC},2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use MID like this:

"33.09789"

```
MID({yourstringhere}, 4)
```

or

```
MID(CSTR({yourstringhere}), 4)
```

it will return a value of 09789;